# Destructuring function parameters in Typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, typescript, express

So I have this little function that takes care of updating a todo document in the database, it looks like so

```
async function update({id, ...todoInfo }: ITodo) { // this line here
    const db = await makeDb()
    const foundTodo = await db.collection('todos').updateOne({ _id: transformId(id) }, { $set: { ...todoInfo } })
    return foundTodo.modifiedCount > 0 ? { _id: id, ...todoInfo } : null
  }
```

The `id` property is meant to come from the req.params object, and the `...todoInfo` comes from the req.body object. But typescript throws an error that `property id does not exist on interface ITodo`. How do I overcome this issue? The interface ITodo looks like this currently,

```
export interface ITodo {
  todo_name: string
  start_time: Date
  end_time: Date
  description: string
  priority: Priority
}
```

I tried this method, but it led to object nesting like so.. `{todoInfo: {todo_name...}}`

```
async function update({id, ...todoInfo }: {id: string, todoInfo: ITodo}) {
    const db = await makeDb()
    const foundTodo = await db.collection('todos').updateOne({ _id: transformId(id) }, { $set: { ...todoInfo } })
    return foundTodo.modifiedCount > 0 ? { _id: id, ...todoInfo } : null
  }
```

I don't want to add the property `id` to the interface because it's either I keep using it everywhere or I could make it optional which will mess up other function calls because the `id` property cannot be undefined. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an intersection type:

```
async function update({ id, ...todoInfo }: { id: string } & ITodo) {
    //...     
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQBUIATCOAbwCg5a4ZSIB9JTAW2AC44BnGKZAHMadPplhMYCDtwAimVCNrAkJSdK5x5iunBLAe2AWCkQk3PgKTDdYAdAQwAntwAK9gc6oBfKlUw8TkjYcOgArsGmSHBhYCQKwAAUFIgkADRwAHTZDGT4SOjk3twpCCQW-EJw3nAAZATEZACUlEpwAPTt2Zm6cD5AA)